# How to rename files in different directories with the same name using find

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, terminal

I have files named `test.txt` in different directories like this

```
./222/test.txt
./111/test.txt
```

I want to rename all `test.txt` to `info.txt`

I've tried using this

```
find . -type f -iname 'test.txt' -exec mv {} {}info \;
```

I get `test.txtinfo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is right, but you need to use `-execdir` instead of just `-exec` to simplify this.

```
find . -type f -iname 'test.txt' -execdir mv {} info.txt ';'
```

This works like `-exec` with the difference that the given shell command is executed with the directory of the found pathname as its current working directory and that `{}` will contain the basename of the found pathname without its path. Also note that the option is a non-standard one (non POSIX compliant).